# System Drive and C: contains boot and bootmgr. Which Boot and bootmgr are being used by Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bootmgr, bcd

I have a machine with Factory installed Windows 7. It has three partitions

1. System Drive
2. Windows Partition (C:drive)
3. Recovery Partiition

Now, there is a folder named **Boot** and a file named **bootmgr** in System Drive as well as in the Windows Partition.

How can I find which Boot and bootmgr are being used by my Windows?

Here are somethings I found:

- Windows issues warning that the file/folder may be in use by Windows when I try to delete any of them.
- System Drive is appearing as **active** when seen from the Windows Disk Management utility

Comment: Don't delete either! The one in use should be the one on the system drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) to specify which disk your machine should boot from under the "BCD install/repair" section. You can then delete the files from whatever drives you didn't select in EasyBCD.

Disclosure: I'm the author of EasyBCD (freeware, award-winner)